# In MTG Arena, does your "rank" affect what cards you can draft?

Tags: mtg-drafting, mtg-arena

In **`Ranked Draft`**, does your own "rank", such as **Bronze Tier 3**, affect the general "quality" of the cards you can draft!?

If you're only **Bronze**, most of the cards you can draft is only **Common** and **Uncommon**, and if you're ranked **Gold**, more chances you got to get **Rare**, even **Mythic Rare**, cards!?

Comment: Is there any reason to think it does?

Comment: The reason being, if it does, then I should wait till my rank is as high as possible before I rashly spend 5k on drafting! ^O^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at all.

The cards you're shown in a draft on MTG Arena are a simulated version of what you would see in a paper draft of MTG cards.

This means that, for each pack, with some exceptions, there will always be 10 commons, 3 uncommons, and 1 rare/mythic rare.

As the draft goes around, simulated players (these would be real players in a paper draft) pick cards, and so the next packs that you see will contain less cards.

If you need more of an explanation, see: https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Booster_Draft

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all, the draft packs are exactly the same on every level. However they are different then the normal arena packs you can buy for gold/gems.

A normal arena pack has 1 rare (which has a 1:8 chance to upgrade to mythic) 2 uncommons and 4 commons.

A draft pack however has 10 commons, 3 uncommons and 1 rare (with the same chance for a mythic).